# How to pass dynamic filename in azure data factory copy activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to copy a (ZIP) file from SFTP source based on current date, I am trying the below expression but it fails, can anyone tell me whats the correct way of doing it ?

[image]

[image]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving dynamic content in the parameter value that's why it is taking whole dynamic content as string which is mentioned in the error. Instead of that create a variable with dynamic content:

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-dd-MM')
```

Use that variable to get file name using below expression:

```
@concat(variables('<variableName>'),'.zip')
```

You will get the file name as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the parameter.Directly add the logic within the pipeline expression.

Currently it is taking formatdatetime as as is string rather than actually calculating because it is being added inside a parameter